# I want to select the greater of the two values from two columns in R

Tags: r

My data looks like:

```
head(myframe)
      id fwt_r fwt_l
[1,] 101    72    52
[2,] 102    61    48
[3,] 103    46    49
[4,] 104    48    41
[5,] 105    51    42
[6,] 106    49    35
```

I want to select the greater of the two values among fwt_r and fwt_l.
I want the output like:

```
72
61
49
48
51
49
```

Kindly help me out. Thanks!

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You are looking for the 'pmax' function

Just run this:

```
pmax(myframe$fwt_r, myframe$fwt_l)
```

pmax means 'parallel maxima' (or vectorized)

Comment: Equivalently, `with(myframe, pmax(fwt_r, fwt_l))`

Comment: Is there a function that does this but with absolute values? I have two vectors which I want to combine. The first vector has values in the first 1:N rows and zero in N+1:2N and the next column has zeroes from 1:N and  values in rows N+1:2N. I want to merge so that I have no zeroes and only get the values from each column

Comment: @EmilKrabbe in your particular case, summing the two columns would get your desired result no?

Comment: sum adds all the elements into a single number. I need element wise addition though.

Comment: yeah i mean like `df$a + df$b`

Comment: I figured it out. I just use `rowSums(cbind(df$Col1,df$Col2))`  thank you for the talk